# External GET requests never finish with some websites regardless of the library used, why?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, axios, http-get

My Google Cloud Functions gets a URL from a database and then retrieves the source of the webpage in question using a GET request. I used Axios, Request, and native HTTP(S) modules.

Most websites work just fine and there is no problem whatsoever. Yet, for that URL `https://www.healthline.com/health/food-nutrition/cricket-flour-nutrition`, Axios and Request just hang forever until my Function times out, but with my native HTTPS tests, it downloads chunks from the url but never finishes, it then hangs until Function timeout.

[image: These are the logs with the status code, the headers from the response, and the chunks i receive... you can see that it's not finished but still hangs until it timeouts.]

My code is pretty simple...

```
const https = require('https');
const newAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });

console.log('-> GET ', document.location.href);

const requestOptions = {
    agent: newAgent,
    hostname: document.location.hostname,
    path: document.location.path
};

var fetchReq = https.request(requestOptions, (res) => {

    let source = '';
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);

    Object.keys(res.headers).forEach(h => {
        console.log('-> ' + h + ' -> ', JSON.stringify(res.headers[h]));
    });

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`-----> CHUNK:`, chunk.substring(0, 40) + ' ... ', chunk.substring(chunk.length - 41, chunk.length - 1));
        source += chunk;
    });

    res.on('close', () => {
        console.log(`-----> CLOSED STREAM`);
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(`-----> STREAM ENDED`);
        try {

            console.log(`-> Fetched`, source.length);
            console.log(`-> Saving to GCS`);

            const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET_RAW);
            const fileName = document.organization + '/' + document.key + '.raw';
            const file = bucket.file(fileName);

            const response = {
                uri: 'gs://' + bucket.name + '/' + fileName,
                data: preCleaning(source)
            };

            const options = {
                gzip: true,
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        kind: document.kind,
                        organization: document.organization,
                        username: document.username,
                        key: document.key,
                        url: document.location.href
                    }
                }
            };

            file.save(response.data, options)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log(`-> Saved to GCS`);
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    reject(new AppError(`Error saving raw document to storage (${uri}).`, 500, err));
                });

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('HTTP message: ', e.message);
        }
    });

    res.on('finish', () => {
        console.log(`-----> FINISHED STREAM`);
    });

    res.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    })

}).on('socket', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('agentRemove');
}).end();
```

I've tried different libraries, the same code works locally, it's just so confusing and I am running out of ideas...

Comment: How long does it take to fetch the data locally?  Are you using a browser, curl, or Node.js to call it locally?

Comment: Nodejs, the very same code. Locally it takes a second to fetch, max.